PowerShell double-quote mangling when executing an external program
Running tock PowerShell 5.1 on a Windows 10 corporate desktop.
I've been using plink [PuTTY] quite successfully from PowerShell to run the same commands on many dozens of Linux servers until now (I haven't previously tried to execute any programs that need " in them).

For example, this works perfectly when passed to plink:
: ; sudo -iu postgres ls -aFl


Whereas this not so much:
# Note the backticks, to preserve the internal double quotes in PowerShell
": ; sudo -iu postgres psql -Xc `"SELECT datname FROM pg_database;`""



Any thoughts on how to fix this? 

Error Example:

Everything is a variable because this code is in a function which builds a slightly different $TheCMD depending on which server I'm looking at:
PS $ $Session = 'FIS-P-CDS-PGS-201'
PS $ $TheCMD = ": ; sudo -iu postgres psql -Xc `"SELECT datname FROM pg_database;`""
PS $ echo $TheCMD

     : ; sudo -iu postgres psql -Xc "SELECT datname FROM pg_database;"


PS $ plink -t -load "$Session" -batch $TheCMD

     psql: warning: extra command-line argument "pg_database" ignored
     psql: FATAL:  role "FROM" does not exist


PS $ $TheCMD = ": ; sudo -iu postgres ls -aFl"
PS $ plink -t -load "$Session" -batch $TheCMD

     total 120
     drwx------   8 postgres postgres  4096 Apr  7 16:36 ./
     drwxr-xr-x. 35 root     root      4096 Nov  9  2021 ../
     drwx------   4 postgres postgres    54 Nov 10  2021 9.6/
     drwxr-xr-x   3 postgres postgres    24 Nov 26 06:48 backups/
     [snip]




The problem is not (just) PowerShell, as the syntax used does pass the double quotes to plink, but that removes them before sending to the remote (see: -sshlog $logfile). To get PowerShell to pass \" to plink:

Use backslash-backtick-dquote to get it to send " to the remote (which then does what you want, assuming your userid is configured with a sane shell, which it appears to be since your simpler case worked) 
If sudoers is set to run the program without prompting, an alternate approach for some programs like psql is to provide input instead of an option:
$cmd = "sudo -iu postgres psql -X"
$in = "SELECT datname from pg_database;"

$in | plink -load $session $cmd




You might try resolving PowerShell variables as a separate step prior to executing the commands in plink, and ExpandString is a built-in function that will do this for you:

I wrote this function that resolves PowerShell variables in the template before passing the expansion down the pipeline:
Get-Content $template | ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_)} 



.

PS doesn't like that: Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline..
